# How to find lowest value inside html table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have this html table created dynamically with datatables jquery plugin...

so I have:

```
<tbody>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 15:33:09</td>
      <td>1230</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>All inclusive</td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 16:01:03</td>
      <td>1309</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>nma</td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 16:01:03</td>
      <td>1900</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>nema</td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 16:08:17</td>
      <td>2000</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>nema poruka za sada</td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 16:32:54</td>
      <td>3900</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>to je to</td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 16:32:57</td>
      <td>1200</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>+magacin</td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 17:43:58</td>
      <td>3400</td>
      <td>2015-09-29</td>
      <td>2015-09-30</td>
      <td>+skladiste + niza cena + tacan da tum utovara</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

How I can find lowest value from second column ?

UPDATE:

I see now that its better to find lowest value from JSON...
so this is my JSON:

```
{"data":[{"vreme":"2015-09-29 15:33:09","cena":1230,"utovar":"","istovar":"","poruka":"All inclusive"},{"vreme":"2015-09-29 16:01:03","cena":1309,"utovar":"","istovar":"","poruka":"nma"},{"vreme":"2015-09-29 16:01:03","cena":1900,"utovar":"","istovar":"","poruka":"nema"},{"vreme":"2015-09-29 16:08:17","cena":2000,"utovar":"","istovar":"","poruka":"nema poruka za sada"},{"vreme":"2015-09-29 16:32:54","cena":3900,"utovar":"","istovar":"","poruka":"to je to"},{"vreme":"2015-09-29 16:32:57","cena":1200,"utovar":"","istovar":"","poruka":"+magacin"},{"vreme":"2015-09-29 17:43:58","cena":3400,"utovar":"2015-09-29","istovar":"2015-09-30","poruka":"+skladiste + niza cena + tacan da tum utovara"}]}
```

How to find lowest value of data.cena ?

Comment: do you want to show us some attempts?

Comment: yes, just to find them

Comment: are you trying to find the lowest value in individual columns?

Comment: no in second column, I try to find lowest value... so 1230, 1309 ...

Comment: do you create the grid from JSON or from HTML? if json, then it's much faster and more reliable to sort the json-based data just before creating the grid. that also make comparing numbers and dates much easier than when they are turned into pretty formatted html.

Comment: yes I grid from JSON ...

Comment: so how to find lowest value from this JSON: {"data":[{"vreme":"2015-09-29 15:33:09","cena":1230,"utovar":"","istovar":"","poruka":"All inclusive"},{"vreme":"2015-09-29 16:01:03","cena":1309,"utovar":"","istovar":"","poruka":"nma"},{"vreme":"2015-09-29 16:01:03","cena":1900,"utovar":"","istovar":"","poruka":"nema"},{"vreme":"2015-09-29 16:08:17","cena":2000,"utovar":"","istovar":"","poruka":"nema poruka za sada"},{"vreme":"2015-09-29 16:32:54","cena":3900,"utovar":"","is ETC ETC...

Comment: Could you please show enough code to reproduce your problem sensibly? Ideally show the JSON (as you have) and the way in which you're converting that JSON into the table element that you (mostly) show? Ideally create a Snippet (using the `</>` button in the editor, rather than just a block of code), which shows the code you already have as it works, and makes it easier for us to adapt in order to help you. It's also worth reading the "[MCVE]" guidelines.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/0hgL1pcp/

Comment: I write  function najniza(){
       $.ajax({
            url: "getaukcija.php",
            type: "POST",
           
            success: function(json) {
          var lowest = $.map(json.data, function(node) {
    return node.cena;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}).shift(); //get the first item out

alert (lowest);
               
            }, 
            error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
   console.log('GRESKA NEKA');
            } 
      
  
});   
   } but dont WORK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, "how do I get the lowest value from a table column?" I'll offer the following function as one approach, albeit I've extended it to identify and return the `<td>` elements with the minimum value, the maximum value, and the nearest-to-mean value(s):

```
// creating a named function, with an 'opts' argument
// to allow for user-customisation:
function valuesInColumn(opts) {

    // these are the 'default' settings of the function,
    // allowing the user to avoid having to set options
    // in the event that the default matches the requirements:

    // columnIndex: Number or numeric String, specifying the
    //              CSS (1-based) index of the column to work
    //              with (defaults to 1, the first <td> element
    //              of its parent <tr>).
    // table:       HTMLTableElement node, upon which the function
    //              should operate (defaults to the first <table>
    //              element in the document).

    var settings = {
        'columnIndex': 1,
            'table': document.querySelector('table')
    };

    // iterating over the properties of the opts argument:
    for (var property in opts) {

        // if the opts Object has a defined property (not
        // inherited from its prototype chain) and the
        // specified property-value is not undefined):
        if (opts.hasOwnProperty(property) && 'undefined' !== opts[property]) {
            // we update the property of the default settings
            // Object to the property-value of the user-defined
            // property-value of the opts Object:
            settings[property] = opts[property];
        }
    }

    // ensuring that the settings.columnIndex is a Number:
    n = parseInt(settings.columnIndex, 10);

    // getting a (non-live) NodeList using querySelectorAll to
    // all <td> elements that are the specific nth-child of their
    // parent <tr> which is itself a child of the <tbody> element
    // within the supplied HTMLTableElement:
    var columnCells = settings.table.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + n + ')'),

     // converting the above NodeList into an Array, using
     // Function.prototype.call() to use the Array method,
     // Array.prototype.slice(), on the supplied NodeList:
        columnValues = Array.prototype.slice.call(columnCells, 0),

     // defining the values to return:
        values = {

            // using Array.prototype.reduce() to reduce the array
            // of cells to the cell containing the maximum value:
            'max': columnValues.reduce(function (v, c) {
                // v: the previously-found-value
                // c: the current array-element over which we're
                // iterating with Array.prototype.reduce().

                // here we use parseInt() to assess whether the
                // number in the cell's text ('c.textContent')
                // is greater than that of the previously-found
                // cell or not; if it is we return the current
                // cell (c) if not we return the previously-found
                // cell (v) using a conditional operator:
                return parseInt(c.textContent, 10) > parseInt(v.textContent, 10) ? c : v;
            }),
                'min': columnValues.reduce(function (v, c) {

                // exactly as above, but here we're testing that
                // the numeric textContent-value is less than
                // that of the previously-found cell:
                return parseInt(c.textContent, 10) < parseInt(v.textContent, 10) ? c : v;
            }),
                'sum': columnValues.reduce(function (v, c) {

                // here we're finding the sum of all the text-values,
                // so we simply add the numeric textContent value
                // of the current Array-element ('c') to the value
                // represented by the previously-found value ('v'):
                return parseInt(v, 10) + parseInt(c.textContent, 10);

            // here we initialise the reduce method's previous-value
            // to 0 in order to guard against accidental 'NaN':
            }, 0),

                // here we again find the sum (as above) but then
                // divide by the length of the Array to find the
                // mean value:
                'meanValue': columnValues.reduce(function (v, c) {
                return parseInt(v, 10) + parseInt(c.textContent, 10);
            }, 0) / columnValues.length
        };

    // iterating over each of the <td> elements in the Array:
    columnValues.forEach(function (c) {

        // setting its 'data-meanDelta' attribute value to the
        // difference between its own text-value and that of the
        // discovered meanValue:
        c.dataset.meanDelta = values.meanValue - parseInt(c.textContent, 10);
    });

    // using Math.prototype.reduce() again, to find the <td>
    // element with the nearest text-value to the found
    // meanValue:
    var firstMeanCell = columnValues.reduce(function (v, c) {

        // here we use parseInt() to convert the
        // dataset.meanDelta property-value of the Node (v)
        // into a decimal Number, and then finding its absolute
        // value (using Math.abs(), so "-10" is coverted first
        // to -10 and then to 10); doing the same to the
        // property-value of the current element(c) and
        // and retaining whichever of the two is the least:
        return Math.abs(parseInt(v.dataset.meanDelta, 10)) < Math.abs(parseInt(c.dataset.meanDelta, 10)) ? v : c;
    }),

        // because it's quite possible for multiple <td> to have
        // the same value it's quite possible that the mean
        // value will be held in multiple cells; so here
        // we filter the array of <td> elements using
        // Array.prototype.filter():
        nearestMeans = columnValues.filter(function (c) {

            // again we get the absolute-value of the
            // dataset.meanDelta property-value of the
            // current Array-element (c) and check if it's
            // equal to that of the firstMeanCell; if it
            // is equal we retain that array element,
            // otherwise it's simply discarded:
            if (Math.abs(parseInt(c.dataset.meanDelta, 10)) === Math.abs(parseInt(firstMeanCell.dataset.meanDelta, 10))) {
                return c;
            }
        });

    // setting the additional properties of the values
    // Object:
    values.means = nearestMeans;
    values.minValue = parseInt(values.min.textContent, 10);
    values.maxValue = parseInt(values.max.textContent, 10);

    // returning the values object to the calling context:
    return values;
}

// setting the columnIndex to 2 (because we want the second
// column and CSS is 1-based, unlike the 0-based JavaScript,
// and caching the returned Object in the 'extremes' variable:
var extremes = valuesInColumn({
    'columnIndex': 2
});

// adding the 'minimum' class-name to the element held
// in the extremes.min property:
extremes.min.classList.add('minimum');

// adding the 'maximum' class-name to the element held
// in the extremes.max property:
extremes.max.classList.add('maximum');

// adding the 'mean' class-name to the first element held
// in the extremes.means property (which is an Array):
extremes.means[0].classList.add('mean');

// logging the other values to the console (in the attached
// demo these are instead logged into the Snippet itself, 
// courtesy of a script from T.J. Crowder - see the HTML
// comments for attribution):
console.log(extremes.sum, extremes.minValue, extremes.maxValue, extremes.meanValue);
```

```js
function valuesInColumn(opts) {
    var settings = {
        'columnIndex': 1,
            'table': document.querySelector('table')
    };

    for (var property in opts) {
        if (opts.hasOwnProperty(property) && 'undefined' !== opts[property]) {
            settings[property] = opts[property];
        }
    }

    n = parseInt(settings.columnIndex, 10);

    var columnCells = settings.table.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + n + ')'),
        columnValues = Array.prototype.slice.call(columnCells, 0),
        values = {
            'max': columnValues.reduce(function (v, c) {
                return parseInt(c.textContent, 10) > parseInt(v.textContent, 10) ? c : v;
            }),
                'min': columnValues.reduce(function (v, c) {
                return parseInt(c.textContent, 10) < parseInt(v.textContent, 10) ? c : v;
            }),
                'sum': columnValues.reduce(function (v, c) {
                return parseInt(v, 10) + parseInt(c.textContent, 10);
            }, 0),
                'meanValue': columnValues.reduce(function (v, c) {
                return parseInt(v, 10) + parseInt(c.textContent, 10);
            }, 0) / columnValues.length
        };

    columnValues.forEach(function (c) {
        c.dataset.meanDelta = values.meanValue - parseInt(c.textContent, 10);
    });
    var firstMeanCell = columnValues.reduce(function (v, c) {
        return parseInt(Math.abs(v.dataset.meanDelta), 10) < parseInt(Math.abs(c.dataset.meanDelta), 10) ? v : c;
    }),
        nearestMeans = columnValues.filter(function (c) {
            if (Math.abs(parseInt(c.dataset.meanDelta, 10)) === Math.abs(parseInt(firstMeanCell.dataset.meanDelta, 10))) {
                return c;
            }
        });

    values.means = nearestMeans;
    values.minValue = parseInt(values.min.textContent, 10);
    values.maxValue = parseInt(values.max.textContent, 10);

    return values;
}

var extremes = valuesInColumn({
    'columnIndex': 2
});

extremes.min.classList.add('minimum');
extremes.max.classList.add('maximum');
extremes.means[0].classList.add('mean');

// Note that in the real - not on SO - world, console.log() would be used much
// more simply, here we use T.J. Crowder's offered 'snippet.log()' approach, 
// as shown in the HTML comments:

var output = ['min', 'max', 'mean'];

output.forEach(function (v) {
  snippet.log(v + ': ' + extremes[v + 'Value']);
});
```

```css
.maximum {
  background-color: red;
}
.minimum {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.mean {
  background-color: aqua;
}

/*
    purely to move the 'snippet.log' output away from the actual HTML content
*/
body p:first-of-type::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 15:33:09</td>
      <td>1230</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>All inclusive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 16:01:03</td>
      <td>1309</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>nma</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 16:01:03</td>
      <td>1900</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>nema</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 16:08:17</td>
      <td>2000</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>nema poruka za sada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 16:32:54</td>
      <td>3900</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>to je to</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 16:32:57</td>
      <td>1200</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>+magacin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">2015-09-29 17:43:58</td>
      <td>3400</td>
      <td>2015-09-29</td>
      <td>2015-09-30</td>
      <td>+skladiste + niza cena + tacan da tum utovara</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/40uymvrz/2/), for experimentation/development.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would suggest updating your code snippet to be more readable. It might encourage more people to answer.

Secondly, a jQuery approach: you could loop through your table rows, grab the second td in each, and store the values in an array. You could then trace through the array to grab the lowestvalue.

```
var values = [];
var lowestVal = 0;

$('tr').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).children('td').eq(1).html();
    lowestVal = value;
    values.push(value);
});


for(var x = 0; x < values.length; x++){
    if(values[x] < lowestVal)lowestVal  = values[x];
}

console.log(lowestVal);
```

### Edit

Ah, I see you've already updated your snippet. Thanks :)

Edit2: Updated to fix errors. Tested.

Comment: I seem them. One moment.

Comment: @PetarAleksic See my updated answer. Also, be sure that your code is surrounded in table tags, I had errors copying what you had.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) as below.

```
var lowest = $("tr td").map(function() {
    //When it's the 2nd td in every row
    if ( $(this).index() === 1 ) {
        return $(this).text();
    }
}).get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}).shift(); //get the first item out
```

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zy66hbqw/)

**Edit:**

For the JSON you've posted, you could do same as above, with slight changes, as below.

```
var lowest = $.map(json.data, function(node) {
    return node.cena;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}).shift(); //get the first item out
```

[**Another Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k1bwamha/)

**Edit:**

Yet another simple approach:

```
var lowest = Infinity; //The value Infinity (positive infinity) is greater than any other number;
json.data.forEach(function(node) {
    lowest = node.cena < lowest && node.cena || lowest;
});
```

[**Another Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/skpkr6yd/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below script:

```
var values = [];
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).text());
    values.push(value);
});
console.log(Math.min.apply(Math,values));
```

Comment: how to do this with JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

First let's wrap your `tbody` inside a `table` to get things to work nicely. After that you can use this code to get the results you are looking for.

First define a `min` function which you can use anywhere else in your code that needs integer `min` functionality. Then we just iterate through all the 2nd column entries and store them in an array as integer values.

Finally, we find the min value in the array and in this case display it in the console.

```
Array.prototype.min = function () {
  return Math.min.apply(Math, this);
};

var colVals = [];

$('tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
  colVals.push(parseInt($(this).text()));
});


console.log(colVals.min());
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ot1f2ax/1/)

**EDIT**

For JSON you can do something like this

```
Array.prototype.min = function () {
  return Math.min.apply(Math, this);
};

var values = [];

for(var i = 0; i < response['data'].length; i++){
  values.push(response['data'][i].cena);
}

console.log(values.min());
```

[**JSFIDDLE JSON**](http://jsfiddle.net/buzx9djp/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `:nth-of-type(2)` to select the second `<td>` element in each `<tr>`

`$('tr td:nth-of-type(2)')` should grab the second `<td>` element.

`$('tr td:nth-of-type(2)').text()` will return the text value, so, 1230, 1309, etc.